# Chart is not displaying updated data

Tags: reactjs, charts, react-chartjs, rerender, react-chartjs-2

I have used https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartjs-2, and it displays a chart with data in the first time. But whenever I try to redraw, using new data and datasets it always displays previous graph data on a chart.

I have tried solutions from: https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2

Also tried to give **reference**

But still, it shows the same data which it loads the first time.

Code to display chart,

```
 <Line
      data={graphData}
      redraw
      options={options}
      height="100px"
      weight="100px"
 />
```

In this,
**graphData** is,
const [graphData, setGraphData] = useState(data);

**redraw**,
I have also tried to do, `redraw={true}`

> When the data will be modified, I use `setGraphData(updatedData)` to update the chart, I have also checked whether data is changed or not.

**Data in graphData updates but not displayed on graph**

***Where the data which is assign as a default data for graphData,***

```
const data = {
    labels: months,
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "# of Users",
            data: [0, 64, 129, 193, 258, 322, 387, 451, 516, 580],
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
            borderColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
            yAxisID: "y-axis-1",
        },
        {
            label: "# of Orders",
            data: [0, 25, 50, 76, 101, 126, 151, 177, 202, 227],
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: "rgb(54, 162, 235)",
            borderColor: "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
            yAxisID: "y-axis-2",
        },
    ],
};
```

**I am creating copy of this data and then assigning in setGraphData()**

Anyone can Help me with this! Thank you in advance!!

Comment: How do you update the data?

Comment: If possible, please provide your code.

Comment: provide a key to the chart component & update the key once the data is updated

Comment: @yahyaparvar, I have one dropdown, in item selection I set data in graphData's setGraphdata. In which I have assigned default data at the time of defining and initializing. I am creating copy of that and then assigning.

Comment: @CharchitKapoor Yes I have updated my question!

Comment: Is it logging, any sort of error on the update? If possible try to generate a minimal working example [link](https://codesandbox.io/dashboard) here.

Comment: No, data updated easily without any error, but the problem is, it is not displaying it on graph!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the code, there is only one solution here. Provide a key to the chart component & update the key once the data is updated,

```
<chart key={getKey()} data={data} />
```

The get key will create a unique key with respect to the new data.

```
  const getKey = () => {
    return data?.map((p) => p.id)?.join();
  };
```

The only thing important here is that the getKey method should return a new value if the data is updated `JSON.stringify(data)` is the simplest option(I am not sure if it is a good approach to provide the serialized data as key, but surely it will work)

Comment: I have updated my question with some code, also I have tried to use, getKey(). Getting error as "TypeError: data.map is not a function".

Comment: @RHF try with <Line  key={JSON.stringify(graphData)}

Comment: thank you, it helped me to debug and check the data.

Comment: <Line key={JSON.stringify(graphData)}> this resolved my issue in chart data render. Can you please update your answer so I can check it as A solution answer!

Comment: @RHF I already mentioned it in my answer.  Read the last paragraph

Answer (score 0):

The issue behind re-rendering was a function defined to call, backend API handler and assigning data to the Line chart.

**Before** - not working

```
useEffect(() => {
      ...
      the function which has code to call and fetch data from back-end API/handler
    }, []);
```

**After** - working

```
useEffect(() => {
       ...
       Code which calls back-end API/handler function to fetch data for graph
       ...
    }, []);
```

I have also keep **redraw**,

```
<Line
     key={JSON.stringify(graphData)}
     data={graphData}
     redraw
     options={options}
     height="100px"
     weight="100px"
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71479953/16414089) while struggling with this issue. Essentially you have to deep clone the data when copying and mutating any values. Works great because you don't need to set `redraw` which causes the jittery animation.